# Self join to fetch data from both the records of a same collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I have an employee collection which has 2 records with different data and we have an employed id as a primary key and the second collection has employee relation id as a forigen key to 1st record’s employeeID.

I want to fetch the data from 2 records and show all the fields of employee data as an output.

Record 1 :
EmployeeID        : 001
Name              : Gouse
Age               : 27
EmployeeRelationID: null

Record 2:
EmployeeID.       :002
Country           : India
EmployeeRelationID: 001

In the output I want to fetch
Name    :Gouse
Age.    : 27
Country : India

Comment: This looks like the most basic use case of `$lookup`. What have you tried so far? what is the current blockage you are facing?

Comment: Can you post some sample documents and your expected output document?